# Passing an int to a class that is contained by another class

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I'm very new to object orientated programming and was wondering if it's possible to pass an int to a class that is contained by another class.
My code compiles but when I run printList in my main the itemID is never printed.

**Here's my ArrayList class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ItemList{
    int itemListID
    String itemName;
    ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
     
    public ItemList(String name, int listID) {
        itemName = name;
        itemListID = listID
    }
    public void addItem(String name, double weight, double price){
        itemList.add(new Item(name,weight,price));
    }
    public int getItemListID(){
        return itemListID;
    }
    public void printItems(){
        for(int i=0; i < itemList.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(itemList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's the class of items contained within the arrayList**

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    double weight;
    double price;
    int itemListID;
  
    public Item(String itemName,double itemWeight, double itemPrice){
        this.name = itemName;
        this.weight = itemWeight;
        this.price = itemPrice;
    }
    public int setItemListID(){
        itemListID = ItemList.getItemListID();
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return(name + " has a weight of " + weight + " and a price of " + price + "item is in itemlist"
        + itemListID);
    }    
}
```

**Here's the main**

```
public class HopefulShopMain{
    public static void main (String[] args){
         ItemList myList = new ItemList("Fruit",1);
         
         myList.addItem("Apple", 100, 60);
         myList.addItem("Banana", 118, 50);
         
         myList.printItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: `+int itemListID` ??? just `itemListID` , also it's ever setValue ?

Comment: Show us more code.  We need to see you create an instance of `ItemList`, add some entries with `addItem()`, then call `printItems()`.

Comment: I think were missing some code here. Can you please add the main as well?

Comment: Your `setItemListID()` shouldn't even compile.  In fact, it seems like it is in the wrong class.  I'd expect to see (in class `ItemList`, not class `Item`): `public void setItemListID(int ID) { itemListID = ID; }`.

Comment: Your code, as shown, still should NOT COMPILE.  At `ItemList.getItemListID();`, there is no STATIC member called `getItemListID()` in class `ItemList`.  There shouldn't be, though...see my previous comment.

Comment: @Idle_Mind yeah, sorry copy and pasted an older version, added the main as well

Comment: @TraianGEICU yep gotten rid of the int thanks so much

Comment: If all you want to do is cause the printItems in main to output the individual "name has a weight of..." you just need to add .toString() on the end of itemList.get(i) in the System.out line

Answer (score 0):

> was wondering if it's possible to pass an int to a class that is contained by another class

Yes. This can be done at various levels (constructor, or method), and in different ways.

In your example, you could pass the itemListID into the Item's constructor:

```
    public void addItem(String name, double weight, double price){
        itemList.add(new Item(name,weight,price,this.itemListID));
    }
```

Then your Item class can keep that value in a field just like it does with the other values it's getting in its constructor.

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    double weight;
    double price;
    int itemListID;
  
    public Item(String itemName,double itemWeight, double itemPrice, int itemListID){
        this.name = itemName;
        this.weight = itemWeight;
        this.price = itemPrice;
        this.itemListID = itemListID;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return(name + " has a weight of " + weight + " and a price of " + price + "item is in itemlist"
        + itemListID);
    }    
}
```

Alternatively, you could pass the entire `ItemList` into the constructor so it can refer to any value that `ItemList` has on it

Or you can make `Item` a (non-static) nested class inside of `ItemList`, so it can simply reference the field directly. This might be appropriate in your case, since it appears you only expect `Item` to be created and accessed by the `ItemList` class itself.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ItemList{
    int itemListID
    String itemName;
    ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
     
    public ItemList(String name, int listID) {
        itemName = name;
        itemListID = listID
    }
    public void addItem(String name, double weight, double price){
        itemList.add(new Item(name,weight,price));
    }
    public int getItemListID(){
        return itemListID;
    }
    public void printItems(){
        for(int i=0; i < itemList.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(itemList.get(i));
        }
    }
    class Item {
        String name;
        double weight;
        double price;
      
        public Item(String itemName,double itemWeight, double itemPrice){
            this.name = itemName;
            this.weight = itemWeight;
            this.price = itemPrice;
        }
        
        public String toString(){
            return(name + " has a weight of " + weight + " and a price of " + price + "item is in itemlist"
            + ItemList.this.itemListID);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: For the first solution will I have to put a itemListID parameter in the addItem method?

Comment: No, because `ItemList` already has an `itemListID` field. You can access it from within non-static methods in `ItemList` (like `addItem`) just like you access any other fields. The "`this.`" there explicitly tells the compiler you're talking about that field, as opposed to some other variable that might share the same name.

Comment: Ah, I see I need two constructors thank you very much

Comment: I would be careful about that decision. The desire to have two constructors may indicate that your class fulfills different responsibilities, which should maybe be divided into two different classes.